# use session storage instead of cookies in auth.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

js(previous next-auth) in my web application and i want to store JWT in session storage instead of cookies. how should i configure it to store JWT in session storage?

my next-auth config:

```
export default {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const validatedField = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials);

        if (validatedField.success) {
          const { username, password } = validatedField.data;

          const user = await getUser(username);
          if (!user || !user.password) return null;

          const passwordMatch = await bcryptjs.compare(password, user.password);

          if (passwordMatch) return user as User;
        }

        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;
```

i looked at config and i didn't saw any option to use session storage.